# Add item in Azure storage queue from workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, azure

I'm trying to add an item in a Azure storage queue from a SharePoint 2013 workflow.

I created a Dictionary named "Header" with two "rows" one with name "Authorization" and the value is: `SharedKey thenameofmystorageaccount:mylongkey==`

And the other row is name "`x-ms-date`" and value is a variable today

as body in the request I created a textstring with the value

```
<QueueMessage>
<MessageText>[%Current Item:ID%]</MessageText>
</QueueMessage>
```

then I added the Dictionary Header in the RequestHeaders properties in the Properties for the HTTP request.

But there has to be something wring with my header because I just gets an "Forbidden" as Response code back from the call

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is a cross origin (CORS) issue. Azure storage now supports setting CORS rules where your can authorize your SharePoint domain. Search on Set-AzureStorageCORSRules.